# Can't delete (and insert) rows anymore in an excel 365 file

Tags: excel, file, row, extract

I ran into an issue with excel 365 last friday. I was copying complete rows to another file (STRG+c and STRG+v) and deleted them afterwards from the source file (STRG+"-"). It worked fine until all over sudden I was just able to delete the data but the rows were still there. I assume that I did some (unknown) shortcut... One more stange thing is that it affects the complete file (more than 10 sheets). The sheets are not protected and the file is neither. I'm alble to add content at the end of each sheet and I can delete sheets. I do have some VBA code in this file with formulars and formatting code. Does anybody know what happend and more important how I can solve the problem?

I cant't restore the data with "step back". I couldn't find anything on google about this. I tried to deactivate the VBA code but no changes.